# According to those who deny a pre-incarnate personhood of Christ, who or what considered/thought/accounted in Philippians 2:5-6?

Tags: non-trinitarian, unitarianism, philippians

> Let this mind be in you, which was also in Christ Jesus:  **Who**, being in the form of God, **thought** it not robbery to be equal with God: - Philippians 2:5-6

Various translations render "*hegeomai*" as thought, consider, regard, count, esteem, deem, reckon, and even a strange "take advantage" (which I think is outside the box).  All of these rightly represent a function of mind, as the object in question (equality with God) is perceived and rationally, accurately considered.

For comparison, the exact same word in the exact same form appears in [1 Timothy 1:12](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Timothy%201%3A12&version=KJV) (he counted) and [Hebrews 11:11](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%2011%3A11&version=KJV) (she judged).

Indeed, we are exhorted to have the same mind in us as was in Christ Jesus when He, Christ Jesus, thought (*hegeomai*) it not robbery to be equal with God **when** He was in the form of God.  Following that consideration he "took upon him the form of a servant". The condescension follows after and flows from the consideration in the text of v. 6-8 just as the exaltation of v. 9 follows after and flows from the condescension.

There are those who declare that, prior to his birth, Jesus did not exist with person-hood and that, if he existed in some form, he existed as "an idea in the mind of God".  Biblical Unitarians are one such group.  However this verse declares that, prior to his birth in Nazareth, Christ Jesus displayed function of mind.  He considered, thought, reckoned, esteemed, or counted.

Additionally, having considered he then acted by "making himself of no reputation" and "took the form of a servant" in accordance with his reckoning.  It is crystal clear from the verse in question that it is the "who" which "thought" and equally clear that the "who" is Christ Jesus prior to his birth in Nazareth.

The who, "being in the form of God", is prior to "in the form of a servant" and "made in the likeness of men" as evidenced by the conjunctive "but" separating the *hegeomai* of equality with God, which took place when in the form of God, and the actions of making himself of no reputation, etc. which result from the *hegeomai*. If the latter activity can be understood as Jesus' birth in Nazareth (and indeed it must if he did not pre-exist his birth), then it is prior to his birth in Nazareth when he considered.

From those who deny a pre-incarnate "person" of Christ; Who or what performed "*hegeomai*", that function of personal, rational mind?

Comment: I took the liberty of editing only to place anglicised Greek words in italics, as is conventional, to avoid them being seen as transliterations. Please roll back if you feel this is intrusive. Up-voted +1.

Comment: On what do you base, "prior to his birth" from that verse? Is it crystal clear in your mind only as the text has no time frame to signal this.

Comment: @steveowen When Jesus "considered it not robbery" was when he was "in the form of God".  Following that consideration he "took upon him the form of a servant".  The condescension follows after and flows from the consideration in the text of v. 6-8 just as the exaltation of v. 9 follows after and flows from the condescension.

Comment: When, according to the text is, 'in the form of God'? No point in answering if you make stuff up within the Q. Your whole premise is an assumption - 'what is the time element' from the text?

Comment: @steveowen It is prior to "in the form of a servant" and "made in the likeness of men".  If these two terms can be understood as Jesus' birth in Nazareth then it is prior to his birth in Nazareth.  If these two terms can be understood as something else, why don't you present that in an answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are reading in your own assumptions. There is no reference to birth in the text, yet you frame the Q as though there was. Please leave out the eisegesis and ask a succinct and accurate Q. IF you are going to base the Q around a verse, let the verse speak on its own and not the imposed traditional bias.

Comment: :) you *seem* to think that being in the form of God is opposite to the form of a servant. Frankly the whole Q is riddled with supposition.

Comment: @steveowen There is a "but" interposed between the two.  From Thayer's 1) but
1a) nevertheless, notwithstanding
1b) an objection
1c) an exception
1d) a restriction
1e) nay, rather, yea, moreover
1f) forms a transition to the cardinal matter

Comment: @steveowen and from Strong's; Neuter plural of G243; properly other things, that is, (adverbially) contrariwise (in many relations):

Comment: @steveowen There is no when or no time element from the text. Jesus was God all along. Greek Scholar A.T Robertson: Being (υπαρχων). Rather, "existing," present active participle of υπαρχω. In the form of God (εν μορφη θεου). Μορφη means the essential attributes as shown in the form. In his preincarnate state Christ possessed the attributes of God and so appeared to those in heaven who saw him. Here is a clear statement by Paul of the deity of Christ. Mike quoted Thayer a Unitarian agrees that a "but" or in my NASB, vs6, "who, although He existed as God. Although means, in spite of the FACT.

Comment: :) “ his preincarnate state”, you don’t have support for his *INcarnation*. Another made up thing to add mystery and confusion.

Comment: @steveowen If Jesus existed prior to his birth (as this verse indicates) then his birth can accurately be called an incarnation.

Comment: Really? I agree that you can make up whatever you like and give it a label! The bible doesn't speak of what you call an incarnation. This verse does not say *anything* about what you suggest.  I cannot fathom the eisegetical hubris here from an otherwise sensible and thoughtful poster. Stick to the text and stop making stuff up.

Comment: @steveowen I have an idea since you just stated, "The bible doesn't speak of what you call an incarnation." Galatians 4:4-5, "But when the fulness of the time came, God sent forth His Son, born of a woman, born under the Law, vs5, in order that He might redeem those who were under the Law, that we might receive the adoption as sons." I could quote about 9 or 10 other verses regarding the incarnation of Jesus Christ. Now, why don't you show me your exegesis of Galatians 4:4-5 in a way that demonstrates how you can deny the obvious of what it says? Or to put it another way, define incarnation?

Comment: I'll exegete it to *your* reading, Gal *insists* God sent His (God)Son from *heaven* to be *born* through a woman. So, the eternal Son who *cannot* die, now has a human ... oh I don't know what you'd do from here??? Why don't you ask a proper question about the alleged incarnation which is so important the bible doesn't even mention it!?

Comment: @steveowen You are most welcome to correct my eisegetical hubris.  A good answer might involve an explanation (from the text, as you say) of when (at what point) Christ Jesus was in the form of God and thought, followed by a demonstration (again from the text) of how that "thought" does not precede the action of taking the form of a servant.  Also helpful would be a textual explanation of why 'taking the form of a servant and being made in the likeness of a man' does not indicate his birth at Nazareth.

Comment: You can ask another Q about those things if you want. I'm not inclined to answer this one though in its current form. I think you need to sort out "when Christ Jesus was in the form of God" first. Prob. better on BH in my view. Too many wild ideas here, that are more related to doctrine than scripture.

Comment: @steveowen https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/69295/does-philippians-25-8-indicate-chronological-progression